# Couldn't find meta-data for provider with authority com.example.fileprovider

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to create a photo app but I'm getting error :

```
 "Couldn't find meta-data for provider with authority com.example.fileprovider"
```

Here is my Android Manifest.xml below :

```
   <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.example.location.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths">

        </meta-data>
    </provider>
```

Here is my file_paths.xml below :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<external-files-path name="my_images" path="Android/data/com.example.location/files/pictures" />
```

And here is part of my MainActivity.java below :

```
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File
            Toast.makeText(this, "something went wrong creating the file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                    "com.example.location.fileprovider",
                    photoFile);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        }
    }
```

And also in the path attribute and authority attribute "-.-.-.fileprovider" is underlined with a green zigzag line,If any more information is needed please inform me. I have tried to check some solution to similar problem but didn't manage to fix mine.

Answer (score 2):

In your XML, you have:

```
android:authorities="com.example.android.fileprovider"
```

So your authority string is `com.example.android.fileprovider`.

In your Java, you have:

```
            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                    "com.example.fileprovider",
                    photoFile);
```

So, your authority string is `com.example.fileprovider`.

These are not the same. They need to be the same. And, ideally, they would be tied to your application ID rather than `com.example`.

Comment: hello, thanks for your reply! iv'e tried what you did suggest but the app still brings the same error the problem is still about "fileprovider" thing as it's highlighted in green zigzag line, and the debugger points to its line in the code, i've edit the question code according to how you did suggest, i'll appreciate if you'll take a look at it again.